# iOS - Detect when gesture ends outside of the origin view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, swipe, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a `UIView` organized with two columns and each column have it own `UIViewController`. I need to hide my left view when the right view receive a swipe gesture with the left direction.

I added a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to the right view and the code works when the gestures *begins* and *ends* in the right view. However, if my gestures *begins* in the right view and *ends* in the left view my event is not triggered.

Anyone know how I can handle this?

Comment: Add the gestureRecognizer to the whole UIView.

Comment: I don't know if that will work. If I add the gesture to the whole view, the user will be able to do the gesture in left view and I have the restriction that the gesture can only work if it begins in the right view.

Comment: You can detect in which view the gesture did began and if it's in the wrong view, you can just ignore it.

Comment: What method I have to use to detect in which view the gesture did began? I think this will solve my problem.